# Conditioning on two normal variables $E[x|y=y_0,x\leq k]$ and obtaining an analytical expression

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

suppose $x=a+e$ and $y=b+e$, where $e$ is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2_e$. $a$ and $b$ are independent and normally distributed, both with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. $a$ and $b$ are also independent of $e$.

Given this,

$$E[x|y=y_0,x\leq z]=E[E[x|y_0]|y=y_0,x\leq z]$$

And since
$$E[x|y_0]=\mu +\frac{\sigma^2_e}{\sigma^2+\sigma^2_e}[y_0-\mu]$$

$$E[x|y=y_0,x\leq z]=E[\mu +\frac{\sigma^2_e}{\sigma^2+\sigma^2_e}[y_0-\mu]|x\leq z]$$

Where am I going wrong here? My original intuition was that the above would imply
$E[x|y=y_0,x\leq z]=\mu -\mu \frac{\sigma^2_e}{\sigma^2+\sigma^2_e}+\frac{\sigma^2_e}{\sigma^2+\sigma^2_e}E[y_0|x\leq z]$ but sice $y_0$ is realized, and not random, it wouldnt make any sense to write it this way.

Comment: Your approach is not good, the problem is more complex than it seems to be. I write a solution by using the conditional expectation below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

First, we prove the vector $(x,y)$ follows a bivariate normal distribution. It suffices to notice that

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
           x \\
           y \\
\end{pmatrix}  = 
\begin{pmatrix}
           1 &0&1 \\
           0&1&1 \\
\end{pmatrix} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
           a \\
           b \\
e\\
\end{pmatrix} =:V\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
           a \\
           b \\
e\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
           a \\
           b \\
e\\
\end{pmatrix}  \stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=} \mathcal{N}_3\left(\begin{pmatrix}
           \mu \\
           \mu \\
\mu_e\\
\end{pmatrix};\begin{pmatrix}
           \sigma^2&0&0 \\
           0&\sigma^2&0 \\
0&0&\sigma^2_e\\ \end{pmatrix} \right)=:\mathcal{N}_3(\Gamma;\Sigma)
$$

We deduce that
$$\color{red}{\begin{pmatrix}
           x \\
           y \\
\end{pmatrix} \stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=} \mathcal{N}_2 \left(V\Gamma; V\Sigma V'  \right)} \tag{1} $$

Second, from $(1)$ and this [result](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case_2), we deduce that the conditional distribution  $x|\{y = y_0\}$ follows a normal distribution. I let you determine the parameters with the [result](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case_2). The density function and probability function of $x|\{y = y_0\}$  are denoted by $f_{x|\{y = y_0\}}(t)$ and $F_{x|\{y = y_0\}}(t)$.

Third, from the property of conditional expectation

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(x|\{y = y_0\} \cap \{x \le z  \}] &= \frac{\mathbb{E}(x\cdot \mathbf{1}_{ \{x \le z  \}}|\{y = y_0\} ]}{\mathbb{P}(x \le z|\{y = y_0\} ]} \\
&= \color{red}{\frac{\int_{-\infty}^z t\cdot f_{x|\{y = y_0\}}(t)dt}{F_{x|\{y = y_0\}}(z)}} \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

You can compute $(2)$ analytically with some easy transformations.